# What is the "proper" method for determining if a swf is running within an AIR application?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, air, module

I've got a Flex Web project and a Flex AIR project that use a common code-base.  The common code defines several run-time loaded Flex Modules.  I want the Flex Modules to behave differently depending on whether the running base application is WEB or AIR.  What is the proper method for determining from the module code whether the module is running in a WEB or AIR application?

(I found that Security.sandboxType.toString() returns "application", but I haven't found anything better in the documentation, yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your Friend:

[How to check if a SWF is running as an AIR app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601904/how-to-check-if-a-swf-is-running-as-an-air-app)

> Use the Capabilities class:

```
> import flash.system.Capabilities;
> 
> switch (Capabilities.playerType) {
>     case 'Desktop':
>         //air runtime
>         break;
>     case 'PlugIn':
>     case 'ActiveX':
>         //browser
>         break; }
```

Comment: Actually, stackoverflow and you deliver better answers without all the noise.  Thanks!

Comment: I Googled it. ;)  The answer just happened to be in a previous StackOverflow question.  I couldn't remember it off the top of my head.